# How to end tasks which works in background

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hello I am making boxing countdown timer and I have the ring that plays at the end and start of each round. I would like to make "end" button but when I am using Intent like bellow I go to previously activity but mp3 files still working in background. How to end all tasks and go to previously activity without any mp3 and tasks in background?

```
 btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder  dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(Main3Activity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Czy napewno chcesz wyjść z trenignu?");
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Tak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Intent intent=new Intent(Main3Activity.this, Main5Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);



                }
            });

            dialog.setNegativeButton("Nie", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialogg=dialog.create();
            dialogg.show();
        }
    });`
```

Answer (score 0):

### removeEventListener()

use HTML DOM removeEventListener() Method

```
btn1.removeEventListener("click", function(){});
```

see: https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks incomplete or incorrect to me.

If you want to go to previous activity from the activity stack, then you should not use intent to start the previous activity, rather finish the current Activity.

If you want to stop playing the bell ring once the user is not interacting with the Main3Activity or when Main3Activity is not visible to the user. Then best practice is to write a code in the onStop() method of the Main3activity to check for the object which is responsible for playing the sound and safely call stop or destroy the object.

Comment: What I should add to my question?

Answer (score 0):

simply finish the activity which can destroy the instance of activity and everything that is running on that particular activity. simply write this line after startActivity

```
finish();
```